# Can the Plague Memorial building be moved?

Tags: stellaris

To not go too much in to detals about this event (the tittle is spoiler enough), can the building be moved, or rebuild after demolishing it?

For me, it popped up to a rather ill opportuned place I'd really rather be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this in game version 2.1.1 and unfortunately the answer appears to be:

**No. It cannot be moved.** If you replace it, or destroy it, it is gone forever and cannot be rebuilt. Unless you are lucky enough to get the event a second time, I suppose. I don't even know if such a thing is possible.

Unfortunately, you have to choose between either the +2 unity or taking advantage of the benefits of whatever tile it landed on. I can think of many cases where you'd probably be better off destroying the building. +2 unity might be nice early-game, but later on, you'll probably want to get rid of the memorial and put something more productive there.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe so but I think u may demolish it and re get it (sorry I'm not up to that)

Comment: This doesn't sound too reassuring...